# Delphi TADOQuery - change table fields definition leads to misbehaviour

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I'm refactoring an existing Delphi VCL application, migrating the underlying DB from Access 97 (!!) to SQL Server 2014.
In the process, we decided for a table to change some field definitions, in particular we changed the field 'Ora' type from **DateTime** to **int**.

I have a TADOQuery on the form, that simply does

```
SELECT * FROM Carichi
```

After changing the 'Carichi' table definition, I deleted all the Fields from the TADOQuery and ran "Add Fields" to add refreshed fields.
Now I can see the 'Ora' Field is a TIntegerField.

But when I run the form, the following exception appears:

```
06/03/2018 11:00:56:qcarichi: Type mismatch for field 'ora', expecting: Integer actual: DateTime:
```

It looks like somewhere the old field type is kept and checked for.

I also tried to completely delete the TADOQuery object from the form and re-insert it from scratch.... no way....
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you use DB aware controls, like e.g. `TDBGrid` where would you left misdefined column?

Comment: Sorry but I found the problem (so trivial that I'm quite ashamed here...)
At design time I had a connection on the new DB, but I discovered in the code that the DB connection string was forced to the old DB....
Unfortunately this is not an application written by me, so I overlooked that part of code....

Comment: _I discovered in the code that the DB connection string was forced to the old DB_  - has to be that, because the e.message says your field object is looking integer but the **database** is sending datetime: Your TField object is correctly defined.

Answer (score 0):

At design time I had a connection on the new DB, but I discovered in the code that the DB connection string was forced to the old DB, because the `e.message` says your field object is looking integer but the **database** is sending datetime: Your TField object is correctly defined.

---

Compilation of the comments by [Stefano Lossi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128257/delphi-tadoquery-change-table-fields-definition-leads-to-misbehaviour/75936618?noredirect=1#comment85261393_49128257) and [Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128257/delphi-tadoquery-change-table-fields-definition-leads-to-misbehaviour/75936618?noredirect=1#comment85287565_49128257).